# How to get the definition of dropped objects in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, database-administration

I accidently dropped the statistics on table. Now I want recreate it. But I dont have the definition. Is there any wat where I can get definition of statistics.

Comment: Do you have a backup? Otherwise, you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you could get it back would be restoring a backup. Other than that, the best thing you can do is re-analyze the table performance and create new statistics based on your analysis; DTA may help you on that.

Comment: I executed the create statistics query for same dropped staistics yesterday. So you do have any sys query by I can get the create statement executed yesterday

Answer (score 0):

dropping anything in sql is pretty much permanent, there's no restoring outside of a database backup - sounds like you unfortunately have quite a bit of work ahead of you if it's important data.